# Change date format in datatables in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

i got date from database with format mm/dd/yyyy
after that i send date to my datatables from controller

```
$fetch_data = $this->model->make_datatables();
foreach($fetch_data as $row){
...
$sub_array[] = $row->date,
...
}
```

is it possible to change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in view or controller
(ex: convert from 03/15/2020 to 15/03/2020 )

Comment: You should look into the mysql query which returns this format and change it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use date() function**

```
date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row->date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible Try this

```
$var = '03/15/2020';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $var);
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the datetime class

```
$fetch_data = $this->model->make_datatables();
foreach($fetch_data as $row){
    ...

    $objDatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row->date);

    $sub_array[] = $objDatetime->format('d/m/Y'),
    ...
}
```

> Take a look at the php documentation - it might help you https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime